# Issue while Authorizing Org to VS Code though two of my org are already connected to VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, visual

Can anyone please help?! I am unable to do Authorize org with VS Code. I have two orgs that are already authorized with VS Code, but I am not able to authorize a new org. It's throwing an error though I can deploy code on org, which is already authorized; only when I am trying to authorize with new org its throwing error.

Any Idea??? It would really as I block to do my priority assignment. Please help

below is error

Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

```
08:13:15.856 sfdx org:login:web --alias vscodeOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension "" for C:\Program Files\sf\client\bin\run. Loading extensionless files is not supported inside of "type":"module" package.json contexts. The package.json file C:\Program Files\sf\client\package.json caused this "type":"module" context. Try changing C:\Program Files\sf\client\bin\run to have a file extension. Note the "bin" field of package.json can point to a file with an extension, for example {"type":"module","bin":{"run":".\bin\run.js"}}
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

Here is My package.json

Node.js v18.15.0
08:13:16.394 sfdx org:login:web --alias vscodeOrg --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
 ended with exit code 1

{
  "name": "salesforce-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Salesforce App",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint **/{aura,lwc}/**",
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest",
    "test:unit:watch": "sfdx-lwc-jest --watch",
    "test:unit:debug": "sfdx-lwc-jest --debug",
    "test:unit:coverage": "sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
    "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc": "^1.1.2",
    "@prettier/plugin-xml": "^2.0.1",
    "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc": "^3.2.3",
    "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura": "^2.0.0",
    "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-lightning": "^1.0.0",
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.2",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.7",
    "prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "**/{aura,lwc}/**": [
      "eslint"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the contents of your package.json in your question? Have you followed the recommendation in the error message "Try changing..."?

Comment: I have added package.json in my question, error message I tried preforming some steps of troubleshooting with help of google but didn't work for me, please see if you could help if there is any issue with json file

Comment: This looks like the project package.json, not the C:\Program Files\sf\client\package.json mentioned. Which operating system do you have, - Windows?

Comment: yes windows 11, What steps should I perform and any changes in json, could you please help

Answer (score 0):

@puja -Check if you have 2 "run" files created in "C:\Program Files\sf\client\bin\run." If yes, you can remove the one without any extension and keep run.js, If you only have one run file, you need to rename it to run.js. This should fix your issue.
Please vote if this fixes your issue so that others can use the same.
[image]